# distribution choice for network latency

Tags: probability-theory, computer-networks

Consider this situation. A few clients are connected to a server over the internet.

I define network latency as the time between request leaving the client and reaching the server.

What distributions (i.e. gaussian, uniform, exponential) do network latencies ***typically*** follow?